# Laravel Jetstream ask me password confirmation when enable 2fa

Tags: laravel, two-factor-authentication, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

When I enable two factor authentication the app ask me password confirmation.
I don't want it ask me password confirmation when I enable 2fa. Can I resolve?
The Jetstream version is 2.7

In config/fortify.php I have:

```
Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirm' => true,
            'confirmPassword' => false,
        ]),
```